# how to change power management settings?

Tags: c#, winapi

I already use PowerReadACValue() method to read current and default value of my current power management profil. But according to [Power Management Functions on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa373163(v=vs.85).aspx) I can't find a method to write a new settings, there is no PowerWriteACValue().

How can I change a setting programmatically ?

Comment: [CallNtPowerInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372675.aspx): *"Sets or retrieves power information."*

Comment: @IInspectable you can't with SystemPowerCapabilities

Comment: Of course not. *SystemPowerCapabilities* returns capabilities of the system, that have to be present in hardware. *SystemPowerPolicyAc* allows you to modify the policy that's in effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PowerWriteACValueIndex() method to set the value.  The only difference between the PowerReadACValue() and PowerReadACValueIndex() is that PowerReadACValueIndex() does the conversion of the buffer into an integer for you.  You can refer to the following post on MSDN forum.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/586d20af-bae5-458e-857d-46f2cbe43290/trying-to-understand-windows-power-configuration-apis